# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule for login page

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Is it possible to use add_rewrite_rule() to change the URL of the Wordpress login page? Something like:

```
function add_login_rule() {   
  add_rewrite_rule(  
    "^login?",  
    "wp/wp-login.php?",  // wordpress is installed in a subdirectory
    "top"
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_login_rule' );
```

The above code will add the rule to the $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules array, but going to /login results in a 404.

I would prefer not to use the .htaccess approach for rewriting to keep this server-agnostic.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For anyone trying to do something like this - KEEP IN MIND: you need to go to Settings / Permalinks and hit Save - that way the permalinks are flushed and this code might work (seems legit at the first sight).

Comment: Have you achieved your objective?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a 'WordPress page' with a url of '/login'. Then in your theme add a 'page template' that emulates the wordpress login form (super easy to do, and you can even create your own look and feel). The template should include the login form, and the target of the form should be the wp_login_url(). Then update your /login 'WordPress page' to use this new 'page template'.